# Not interpret html in iframe but get the information from the html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iframe

In order to reduce the time of executing, we decide not to show the table in the iframe as the client cant see it. But we have to copy the contents of the table so as to update the table in the main page (which can be seen by the client).

The principle is that, **the iframe shouldn't interpret html, but through a function written by JavaScript, we copy the updated table to the main page.**
We've thought about commenting the html out in the iframe, but it'll be very complicated as we could not get the element by *Document.getElementById(Id)*. And we'll have to parser the html.
Does anybody do similar things?

Comment: What's wrong with using an invisible `div` to put your table in (`display: none`)?

Answer (score 0):

Is the document you're requesting on the same domain as the "main page"? If so, you can request the second document via AJAX and use a regular expression to extract the  element from it. This is all done without rendering any additional content to the DOM.

Once you have the table element extracted from the AJAX response, you can add it to the main page DOM.

Comment: You mean in the JavaScript function, we use the regular expression to extract the element from the document?

Comment: But I see from the Internet that they say using regular expression to parse the html is too complicated, it is better to use Parser, but I don't know whether it will be possible with AJAX or not, do you have any idea?