# Method to change self-closing tags to explicit tags in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

Does there exist a method or function that can convert the self-closing tags to explicit tags in Javascript?
For example:

```
<span class="label"/>
```

converted to :

```
<span class ="label"></span>
```

---

I would like to copy a new HTML from the iframe to the outerHTML of the main page, as the new HTML generated contains self-closing tags, the outerHTML doesn't recognize them and then doesn't change and the page doesn't show correctly. But when the format is standard, that is,with the non-self-closing tags, the outerHTML will take the new HTML,and the page shows perfectly.This is why I would like to change the tags.

---

### And this html is in a string

In fact, I don't want to parse HTML, I just want to find the "< span.../>"and replace it with "< span...>< /span>"

Comment: @Marcel — only in XML mode. Since the end tag for span elements is required in HTML 4, it won't get inserted until you hit the start tag for something it can't contain.

Comment: @David: I stand corrected. I *assumed* browsers would resolve this kind of 'tag soup' correctly, but I know they don't.

Comment: They do resolve it correctly … as per the rules laid out in HTML 5. :)

Comment: @David:In fact no, the web page shows incorrectly, that's why I would like to change.

Comment: "What you want" and "What they spec says is correct" are different things. Once the browser has rendered the page, it only has a DOM and it is far too late to try to patch up broken HTML. Fix the HTML before it gets to the browser's HTML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all, I finally use the silly method to change the self-closing tags, maybe it'll help someone like me:

```
var splitSpan = textHTML.split(">");
var i=0;
for(i=0;i<splitSpan.length-1;i++){
    var lengthSpan = splitSpan[i].length;
    var subSpan = splitSpan[i].substring(1,5);
    var endSpan = splitSpan[i].charAt(lengthSpan-1);
    
    if(subSpan=="span" && endSpan=="/")
    {           
        splitSpan[i]=setCharAt(splitSpan[i],lengthSpan-1,'>');
        splitSpan[i]=splitSpan[i]+"</span>";
    }
    else
    {
        splitSpan[i]=splitSpan[i]+">";
    }
}
```

---

```js
function setCharAt(str,index,chr) {
    if(index > str.length-1) return str;
    return str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

try this to replace all self closing tags out of your string (xml/html)

```
function removeSelfClosingTags(xml) {
    var split = xml.split("/>");
    var newXml = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length - 1;i++) {
        var edsplit = split[i].split("<");
        newXml += split[i] + "></" + edsplit[edsplit.length - 1].split(" ")[0] + ">";
    }
    return newXml + split[split.length-1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use regex:

`var spansFixed = htmlString.replace(/<span(.*)\/>/g, '<span$1></span>');`

Comment: Just commenting here in case someone uses this method; I wouldn't use regex for that eg this is caught. `<span><label>test test</label></span><div />` matches from <span> to <div />

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any need for this, as they will automatically be converted by the browser. This can be demonstrated by:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<span/>';
var span = div.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
span.innerHTML = 'hello';
alert(span.innerHTML);
```

**Edit:** It seems this will only work only in XML mode.

Comment: Not always true. Try this: `var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<span/>Hello';
var span = div.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
alert(span.innerHTML);` If the span was empty then it would not contain Hello. XHTML self-closing tags do not work in text/html documents.

Comment: `<foo />` does not mean the same in HTML 4 (A foo start tag followed by a greater than sign) as it does in XHTML (A foo self-closing tag) or HTML 5 (A foo start tag with some syntactic sugar for people addicted to XML). Browsers tend not to support the HTML 4 syntax at all, and only support the XHTML syntax in documents with XML mime types. The HTML 5 syntax describes the buggy implementation that browsers made when they tried to implement HTML 4.

Comment: Thank you very much for what you offered, but I don't think this is what I need. As the self-closing tags are created by a xsl file, all i can do is to have a method to change the self-closing tags to non-self-closing ones, could you help me?

Comment: And you want your implementation in Javascript?

Comment: Sorry this is way over my head, I'm not sure if it's even possible to do in Javascript, and with the varying methods of ways in which browsers intrepret HTML differently, I predict a nightmare ahead. You haven't actually explained the reason why you want to do this in the first place. What is it about self enclosing tags that annoys you? ;-)

Comment: @Gary I would like to copy a new HTML from the iframe to the outerHTML of the main page, as the new HTML generated contains self-closing tags, the outerHTML doesn't recognize them and then doesn't change and the page doesn't show correctly. But when the format is standard, that is,with the non-self-closing tags, the outerHTML will take the new HTML,and the page shows perfectly.This is why I would like to change the tags.

Comment: @Jamie – Uhm, what? Does simply copying DOM nodes not work? And you can't do an XSLT translation on the server side? That would be way more clear.

Comment: @Marcel As all the nodes are in the comments, we can't copy the nodes directly...

Comment: But why are all the nodes in comments? Why not refactor the back-end, so you can more easily access those nodes?

Comment: @Marcel That's because of the iframe, that's another question I've posted, and finally we found this solution. I think to replace the self-closing tags is not so hard, but I don't know whether Javascript has this kind of method. Or it is better to use regular expression.

Comment: @Jamie: Noooooooooooooooooo: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). I'll have a look at the other question, because I don't understand what it is you're actually after. Uhm, *where* did you post that question? Can't you register an account, so it is more easy for us to see all your questions?

Comment: @Marcel It's very kind of you. I just fogot to post the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964201/not-interpret-html-in-iframe-but-get-the-information-from-the-html

Comment: @Jamie: FYI, I added a comment at your previous question, as that is where the actual problem resides.